# Modify Default Group for new Users in Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, group

I would like to change the default group for new users which are added to the system. Does anybody know in which file this is stored?

I'm using Solaris 11

Answer (score 2):

See the man page for useradd, specifically the -D flag. You would use

```
useradd -D -g newusergroupname
```

The same is true for roleadd

Answer (score 1):

Initial defaults values are hardcoded in `useradd` binaries so you have no access to them.

Should you modify one of the defaults values using the command already provided by Timothy Butler (`useradd -D ...`), a file named `/usr/sadm/defadduser` is created to persistently store the settings.